# I would like to receive the notification of a particular app to Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

Is there any way I can get information about the app's notification through xamarin?

likes

AndroidSystem : The new update is availabe;

i would get that string"The new update is availabe"
what can i do?

Comment: @Anand doesn't seem like what he is looking for. NotificationListenerService is more like it.

Comment: @Cheesebaron I thought he need to check the latest version from store

Comment: It is not what they are asking about. Read the first sentence. The new update is available is an example of a notification...

Comment: nono jusy to check for incoming notifications in Xamarin Android

Comment: @Carrot135 Do you mean that want to check for all incoming notifications the same as the android system ?